# How to get the id to be inserted in the database before insert in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-5

I want to get the id that to be inserted before insert in laravel 5.2. Is there any way or it is possible to achieve this? Suppose I have one table is of transactions. This table has 5 ids, I want to get the 6th id. Please help me. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is this auto incrementing id as laravel default?

Comment: i know about lastinsertedid but i don't know about the auto increment id

Comment: can you share tha table structure with 5 ids ?

Comment: If the identifier is `auto_increment`, then what you're after isn't possible, no matter what anyone tells you. You need to solve your problem from a different angle.

Answer (score -2):

Simply, you can sort the records in descending order to find out last record.

```
$obj = DB::table('table_name')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
```

`$obj->id` gives you the last record's id. According to that you can decide next id value.

Comment: no i don't want to get the id with the help of lastinsertedid this is not the right way

Comment: You can't decode what next id value is. By definition, in concurrent environment, you will never be able to obtain the value of next auto-incremented number.

Answer (score -2):

If you are in User Controller then use bellow code

$userAll=User::all();
$lastId=$userAll->first()->id;

I think helps it.